# Is Apache Directory Server 1.5.x stable enough to use for integration testing purposes

Tags: apacheds

I have been trying to locate various dependencies and it seems that various classes have changed packages resulting in broken stuff. eg AbstractServerTest ffrom 1.5.5 doesnt work with all the jars from 1.5.7. I am wondering if its a good thing to use ADS 1.5. The documentation seems to imply releases are ok, but the download links include "unstable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though many people use it in production, we call them "unstable" cause of historical reasons. These 1.5.X releases are not backward compatible so mixing the jars of different versions won't work. 
If you are just evaluating I urge you to give the latest trunk a try, it has many new features and 
comes with a great testing framework which makes testing of LDAP application easy.